# C++ What's the difference between "using tcp=x" to "namespace tcp=x"

Tags: c++, namespaces, using

What is the difference between these two lines of code:

```
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;
namespace http = boost::beast::http;
```

for example: [Boost Beast HTTP client example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/beast/example/http/client/sync/http_client_sync.cpp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `using tcp=x` creates a type alias for the type `x`, while `namespace tcp=x` creates a namespace alias for the namespace `x`.

So you can't use namespace alias on types, nor can you use a type alias on namespaces.

Comment: And does it have any actual difference that affect how to use it and when?

Comment: When `x` is a namespace, you can create a namespace alias for it. When `x` is a type, you can create a type alias for it. You can use aliases to avoid repeatedly typing names that would otherwise be longer than you'd like - in that regard they are not different.

Comment: @CfirTSabari There is a difference: You cannot create a type alias for a namespace, since a namespace isn't a type.

Comment: So the difference is that you can't use namespace alias on types(you can do the opposite declare type alias for namespace) .
So we should probably always use namespace alias when can.
Thanks.

Comment: @CfirTSabari no, you can only create a namespace alias for a namespace, and you can only create a type alias for a type. You cannot create a type alias for a namespace, and you cannot create a namespace alias for a type.